# Were there subtitles for the non-English bits in Hotel Mumbai?

Tags: subtitles, hotel-mumbai

Were there subtitles for the non-English bits in Hotel Mumbai in the theatrical release?

I'm watching a BluRay version. The "English" and "English (SDH)" subtitles don't have any subtitles for the non-English bits. I was wondering if this was just a mistake. Or if even on the theatrical release, there were no subtitles for the non-English bits (and this was maybe a deliberate choice by the producers).

<s>All the subtitle files I've tried to find online have the same problem (of course, probably they are all from the same BluRay release).</s> After trying many, I finally found [these subtitles](https://www.mimastech.com/cs_download/tmp_searcher/Hotel-Mumbai_2018_English-ELSUBTITLE.COM-ST_34234620.srt) ([Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20230925043936/https://www.mimastech.com/cs_download/tmp_searcher/Hotel-Mumbai_2018_English-ELSUBTITLE.COM-ST_34234620.srt)) that cover the non-English bits.